# Use Same Settings for All Inserted Media?

Tags: php

When you insert a bunch of images into a Wordpress post via "Add Media," you can hit Shift or Ctrl and select several of them at the same time. But is there a way to be able to set the same "Attachment Display Settings" for all of these images? Like, you highlight all of the images you want, select "Medium," and then that setting gets applied to all of the images you have selected so that they're all "Medium" for their individual dropdown?

Thanks!